# Auto complete text remaining on screen

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-sdk-2.1

Does anyone know why the search text remains on the bottom of screen (as shown in image below).  Steps to get there:

- Choose to search for location
- qwerty keyboard comes up
- auto complete bar appears above qwerty

[image]

- hit "Done" and the auto complete text remains on screen and relocates to bottom, but search is called

[image]

.  This does not happen all the time.

- With KeyEvent.ACTION_UP the search text "sticks" to screen when clicking "Done" ... goes directly to search
- With KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE, "Done" closes the qwerty and user must click search button to begin search

Comment: Show us the code of where your using ACTION_UP , it sounds like your not returning to the superclass to let it deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want any word, I think the keyboard do that with predictive text. If only want a list of items ( only countries ) you should use a Spinner.